# PyXB kml and gx extensions

Tags: schema, kml, pyxb

I am trying to create bindings using the kml schema http://schemas.opengis.net/kml/2.2.0/ogckml22.xsd and the gx extension schema https://developers.google.com/kml/schema/kml22gx.xsd

I have no trouble generating and using the bindings generated from the ogckml22 schema. I am unclear as to how to incorporate the extension schema into these bindings.

Answer (score 0):

You don't incorporate the schema into those bindings.  You generate a new bindings module for the extending schema (which has its own namespace), and make sure it references the existing bindings.  Something like this[*]:

```
pyxbgen \
  --archive-path='&pyxb/bundles/opengis//' \
  --schema-location=http://code.google.com/apis/kml/schema/kml22gx.xsd \
  --module=kml22gx
```

The bindings for `kml22gx` will be subclasses of the `pyxb.bundles.opengis.ogckml22` bindings that are being extended.

Look at the file `pyxb/bundles/opengis/scripts/genbind` which is what generates the bindings in PyXB itself.  Several of the namespaces extend other OpenGIS namespaces for which bindings were generated in an earlier invocation of pyxbgen.

([*] When you do this, you may [get an AssertionError](https://github.com/pabigot/pyxb/issues/18).  Comment out the assertion; it seems to be too restrictive.)